# To get the same value and key and display the matched ones

Tags: php

There are 2 array which contain numbers of values in integer form.
I want to show the matched values of the array which contain integer. 
Expected time complexity: O(n) or less
I want a result like 
a20=e20 
b40=f40
c60=g60
d80=h80 
As far as I tried

```
<?php
$a1=array("a"=>"20","b"=>"40","c"=>"60","d"=>"80");
$a2=array("e"=>"20","g"=>"60","f"=>"40","h"=>"80");

$c = array_intersect($a1, $a2);
var_dump($c);
$d = array_intersect($a2, $a1);
var_dump($d);


   foreach ($a1 as $a1key => $a1value) {
      foreach ($a2 as $a2key => $a2value) {
         if ($a1value = $a2value){
            echo $a1key . $a1value .'='. $a2key . $a2value  ?> <br /> <?php ;  

         }

      }

   }

 ?>
```

which results

```
array (size=4)
 'a' => string '20' (length=2)
  'b' => string '40' (length=2)
 'c' => string '60' (length=2)
 'd' => string '80' (length=2)
 array (size=4)
 'e' => string '20' (length=2)
 'g' => string '60' (length=2)
 'f' => string '40' (length=2)
 'h' => string '80' (length=2)
  a20=e20 
  a60=g60 
  a40=f40 
  a80=h80 
  b20=e20 
  b60=g60 
  b40=f40 
  b80=h80 
  c20=e20 
  c60=g60 
  c40=f40 
  c80=h80 
  d20=e20 
  d60=g60 
  d40=f40 
  d80=h80
```

Comment: You can sort the first array and then just search for the value in the second array and if it finds it display it.

Comment: if ($a1value == $a2value){ } use == equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo](https://eval.in/594383)

The **three** fastest ways:
**(0.016 sec real, 0.018 sec wall, 14 MB, 45 syscalls)**

```
$a1=array("a"=>"20","b"=>"40","c"=>"60","d"=>"80");
$a2=array("e"=>"20","g"=>"60","f"=>"40","h"=>"80");
$values = [];

foreach ($a1 as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($values[$value])){
        $values[$value]['1'] = $key;
    }
}

foreach ($a2 as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($values[$value])){
        $values[$value]['2'] = $key;
    }
}

//d($values);
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    if(2 == sizeof($value, $mode))
        echo $value['1'] . $key .'='. $value['2'] . $key '.<br />' ;
}
```

result:

```
a20=e20 
b40=f40 
c60=g60 
d80=h80
```

or without last loop

**(0.012 sec real, 0.013 sec wall, 14 MB, 42 syscalls)**

```
   $a1=array("a"=>"20","b"=>"40","c"=>"60","d"=>"80");
    $a2=array("e"=>"20","g"=>"60","f"=>"40","h"=>"80");
    $values = [];

    foreach ($a1 as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($values[$value])){
            $values[$value]['1'] = $key;
        }
    }

    foreach ($a2 as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($values[$value])){
            echo $values[$value]['1'] . $value .'='. $key .$value. '<br />';
        }
    }

a20=e20 
c60=g60 
b40=f40 
d80=h80
```

or without flip

**(0.012 sec real, 0.014 sec wall, 14 MB, 46 syscalls)**

```
$a1=array("a"=>"20","b"=>"40","c"=>"60","d"=>"80");
$a2=array("e"=>"20","g"=>"60","f"=>"40","h"=>"80");

$flipedA1 = array_flip($a1);

foreach ($a2 as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($flipedA1[$value])){
        echo $flipedA1 [$value] . $value .'='. $key . $value ."<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**(0.012 sec real, 0.025 sec wall, 14 MB, 45 syscalls)**

```
$a1=array("a"=>"20","b"=>"40","c"=>"60","d"=>"80","p"=>"25");
$a2=array("e"=>"20","g"=>"60","f"=>"40","h"=>"80","k"=>"21");

foreach ($a1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($keyA2 = array_search($value, $a2)) {
        printf('%s%d = %s%d', $key, $value, $keyA2, $value);
    }
}
```

Flip arrays

**(0.008 sec real, 0.009 sec wall, 14 MB, 45 syscalls)**

```
$a1=array("a"=>"20","b"=>"40","c"=>"60","d"=>"80","p"=>"25");
$a2=array("e"=>"20","g"=>"60","f"=>"40","h"=>"80","k"=>"21");

$flipA1 = array_flip($a1);
$flipA2 = array_flip($a2);

foreach ($flipA1 as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $flipA2)) {
        echo $value . $key . ' = ' . $flipA2[$key] . $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**(0.008 sec real, 0.008 sec wall, 14 MB, 80 syscalls)**

```
    <?php

    $a1=array("a"=>"20","b"=>"40","c"=>"60","d"=>"80");
    $a2=array("e"=>"20","g"=>"60","f"=>"40","h"=>"80");
    $values = array();

    foreach($a1 as $key1=>$row1)
    {
      foreach($a2 as $key2=>$row2)
      {
          if($row1==$row2)
          {
            $values[] = $key1.$row1.'='.$key2.$row2;
          }

      }

    }

    print_r($values);
    ?>
```

[eval](https://eval.in/594333)